# Policy Map issue on c6848x 15.2(02)SY

Tags: cisco-catalyst, qos, traffic

I have a problem creating traffic shaping on c6848x.

I need to set shaping on output interface to limit and shape traffic to 100 MBs.

So far I did this:

```
class-map match-any 100MB-OUT
match any



policy-map type lan-queuing 100MB-OUT

class class-default

shape average 95000000



int TE1/1/11

service-policy type lan-queuing output 100MB-OUT
```

But I do not see policy applied on interface. No Shaping.

Can you help me with this and what I did wrong?

Comment: Is that a layer-2 interface?

Comment: yes that is layer 2